# Document class creation tutorial

Tags: documentclass-writing

Do you know any tutorial for create document class?

I create my own documentclass by editing book class but not everything works fine.

Thanks for help.

Comment: `texdoc clsguide`

Comment: Apart from `clsguide` there's also http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/flynn/flynn.pdf and to some extent http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-3/robertson/robertson.pdf.

Comment: further possible duplicates can be found by browsing the tag {documentclass-writing} ...

Comment: If you're able to read German you may have a look here: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1479/wie-erstelle-ich-eine-eigene-dokumentenklasse